# How to use PropType inbuilt functions inside a custom validator?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I was having this validator(`array` of specific shape) for defaultValue prop:

```
defaultValue: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        key: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]).isRequired,
        value: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }))
```

but, now `defaultValue` can be of `string` type as well. So I am trying a custom validator :

```
defaultValue: function (props, propName, componentName) {
  if (typeof props[propName] === "string"){

  } else if (props[propName] instanceof Array){
      //how to add old functionality here?
  } else {
      return new Error(
        `Invalid prop ${propName} supplied to ${componentName}. Validation failed`
      )
  }

}
```

Can I use the old `PropTypes.arrayOf(....)` inside the custom validator? I want to add the old validation into the new custom validator function. If using `PropTypes` is not possible, how to achieve the same using custom code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to make default value either a string, or your custom type, you can use oneOfType with string, and your type and it would work.

```
PropTypes.oneOfType([
      PropTypes.string,
      PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
                key: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, 
                                          PropTypes.number]).isRequired,
                value: PropTypes.string.isRequired}))
])
```